# PHP Send Get Request From Client

Tags: php, ip

Hello i want ask basic something.

Trying to get ip with api,file_get_contents and curl sending requests from server so i taking ip of server. Want send request from client for get real ip.

```
$ip = file_get_contents('https://api.ipify.org/);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot quite comprehend the last sentence of your question: "Want send request from client for get real ip." If you want any clarification, please comment below.

If you want to get the server's ip address.

```
$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
```

Or, you want to get a visiting client's ip address.

```
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

You can use these PHP server global variables.
For more reference, please visit the [PHP official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: I can get ip with $_server but didnt want, i want send get request like javascript.

Comment: Do you want to get the server's ip or the client's?

Comment: For your code in the question, the variable $ip do have the server's ip address. I am not really sure what is the problem. Where do you want to send GET request?

Comment: For proxy scenarios you may try `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` as well

Comment: if you write my code to php and go example.com/ip.php u seen example.com's ip, and i dont want use $_SERVER

Comment: Yes, it does. I had tried, I am not sure how can I help you.